# centos yum fails installing anything or updating system

Tags: centos, yum

I am trying to install a package on CentOS, but it throws error when I run the "yum" command. The internet connection is working fine.
I try to yum clean all but problem persist.

Error:

```
[root@dcos-master3 ~]# yum install ntp

Loaded plugins: fastestmirror


     One of the configured repositories failed (Unknown),
     and yum doesn't have enough cached data to continue. At this point the only
     safe thing yum can do is fail. There are a few ways to work "fix" this:

         1. Contact the upstream for the repository and get them to fix the problem.

         2. Reconfigure the baseurl/etc. for the repository, to point to a working
            upstream. This is most often useful if you are using a newer
            distribution release than is supported by the repository (and the
            packages for the previous distribution release still work).

         3. Run the command with the repository temporarily disabled
                yum --disablerepo=<repoid> ...

         4. Disable the repository permanently, so yum won't use it by default. Yum
            will then just ignore the repository until you permanently enable it
            again or use --enablerepo for temporary usage:

                yum-config-manager --disable <repoid>
            or
                subscription-manager repos --disable=<repoid>

         5. Configure the failing repository to be skipped, if it is unavailable.
            Note that yum will try to contact the repo. when it runs most commands,
            so will have to try and fail each time (and thus. yum will be be much
            slower). If it is a very temporary problem though, this is often a nice
            compromise:

                yum-config-manager --save --setopt=<repoid>.skip_if_unavailable=true

    Cannot find a valid baseurl for repo: base/$releasever/x86_64
```

My yum repolist is the next:

```
[root@dcos-master3 ~]# yum repolist list
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
https://yum.dockerproject.org/repo/main/centos/%24releasever/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTPS Error 403 - Forbidden
Trying other mirror.
To address this issue please refer to the below knowledge base article

https://access.redhat.com/solutions/69319

If above article doesn't help to resolve this issue please create a bug on https://bugs.centos.org/

repolist: 0
```

If I list the repolist:

```
[root@dcos-master3 ~]# yum repolist
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
https://yum.dockerproject.org/repo/main/centos/%24releasever/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTPS Error 403 - Forbidden
Trying other mirror.
To address this issue please refer to the below knowledge base article

https://access.redhat.com/solutions/69319

If above article doesn't help to resolve this issue please create a bug on https://bugs.centos.org/

repo id                             repo name                             status
base/$releasever/x86_64             CentOS-$releasever - Base             0
dockerrepo/$releasever              Docker Repository                     0
extras/$releasever/x86_64           CentOS-$releasever - Extras           0
updates/$releasever/x86_64          CentOS-$releasever - Updates          0
repolist: 0
```

Comment: Thanks! I add the output to the description. Can you check? @MichalHainc

Comment: @MichalHainc Yes it throws the next: "[dockerrepo]
name=Docker Repository
baseurl=https://yum.dockerproject.org/repo/main/centos/$releasever/
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=https://yum.dockerproject.org/gpg".

Comment: @MichalHainc it throws "package centos-release is not installed"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

BEFORE TRYING ANY OF THIS, HAVE A BACKUP OF YOUR MACHINE, YOU COULD DAMAGE YOUR OS MORE/COMPLETELY

It seems that your yum variable $releasever is somehow corrupt, 
it usually is caused by missing centos-release package on the machine for some obscure reasons.

You can check if you have the package by:

```
    rpm -qi centos-release
```

You will  probably see:

```
    "package centos-release is not installed"
```

First find out the exact centos version that you have by executing as root:

```
    cat /etc/redhat-release
```

You will see something like this:

```
    CentOS Linux release 7.3.1611 (Core)
```

You can fetch the centos-release package from repo by:

```
    wget http://vault.centos.org/centos/7.3.1611/updates/x86_64/Packages/centos-release-7-3.1611.el7.centos.2.5.x86_64.rpm
```

Now run reinstall centos-release package via rpm:

```
    sudo rpm -Uvh --replacepkgs centos-release-7-3.1611.el7.centos.2.5.x86_64.rpm
```

As next you can try to install something with yum and you might get:

```
    [root@dcos-master3 ikerlan]# sudo yum install wget
    error: db5 error(-30969) from dbenv->open: BDB0091 DB_VERSION_MISMATCH: Database environment version mismatch
    error: cannot open Packages index using db5 - (-30969)
    error: cannot open Packages database in /var/lib/rpm
    CRITICAL:yum.main:

    Error: rpmdb open failed
```

Now you can try to reboot the machine or try to use the following command to rebuild the rpm db:

```
    rpm --rebuilddb
```

Comment: When I try the "--replacepkgs" step I receive 6 errors in the nature of, "file /etc/os-release from install of centos-release-7-9.2009.1.el7.centos.x86_64 conflicts with file from package redhat-release-server-7.9-6.el7_9.x86_64"

Comment: @michalh I have tried your answers, I am seeing the error `package centos-release is not installed` . at `cat /etc/redhat-release` I  have `CentOS Linux release 8.5.2111` to reinstall centos-release package via rpm I don't see the 8.5.2111 in the repository website. 

and also I am not able to to yum, trying to install `dnf yum install` throwing the error `Error unpacking rpm package yum-4.7.0-4.el8.noarch` 
Do you have any suggestions for me?

Answer (score 1):

I came across the same issue while downloading some packages in centos 7. After days of search, I found the solution:

1. Go to the yum repo directory.

   ```
    cd /etc/yum.repos.d.
   ```
2. Make a copy of the CentOS-Base.repo file.

   ```
    cp CentOS-Base.repo CentOS-Base.repo.old
   ```
3. Edit the CentOS-Base.repo file. Comment mirrorlist and uncomment baseurl.

   ```
    vi CentOS-Base.repo
   ```

```
    [base]
    name=CentOS-$releasever - Base
    #mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=os&infra=$infra
    baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/os/$basearch/
    gpgcheck=1
    gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7
```

4. Now when you use yum, do the following.

   ```
    sudo yum --disablerepo=* --enablerepo=base install httpd
   ```

Likewise for yum update.

```
  sudo yum --disablerepo=* --enablerepo=base install httpd
```

It should work now.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem when attempting to install MariaDB on CentOS 7. I was super frustrated and after much searching found the answer at this [link](https://www.linux.com/learn/intro-to-linux/2017/2/best-third-party-repositories-centos).

Here is what fixed this problem for me.  Run as root.

```
# yum --disablerepo "*" --enablerepo epel install [package]
# yum clean all
```

"epel" can be whatever repo you like, but this one worked for me.  Place [package] in the command just as written, not what package you are trying to install.

After you run the above, exit root and run whatever install you were attempting before encountering the error.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that in the failing url, your `$releasever` is `%24releasever`, but it should be `7` or `7.14.xx`. Please check your yum config file at `/etc/yum/var`, or search in every `.repo` file, to see what is its value. It may be corrupted.

See Red Hat documentation for more information about how to set these variables.

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/deployment_guide/sec-using_yum_variables

Answer (score 0):

```
yum install http://rpms.remirepo.net/enterprise/remi-release-7.rpm -y
yum -y install yum-utils
yum-config-manager --enable remi-php74
```

Then proceed to your installation/updates/etc

Answer (score 0):

Always make sure NAT is active on your centos7. Specially when there is a VMnet2 for host. Because sometimes VMNet2 can be active instead of NAT and because of that you will not be able to connect to the internet through centos7. This is just a one reason for getting that error.